# How to save Pane or GUI on javafx

Tags: user-interface, javafx, save, nodes

I read a lot of solutions for how to save an object,
but how can I save a complex node in JavaFX like a pane with other panes or nodes inside? Also, I would like to save the state the text of TextField.
Is there any API that I can save the object as it is?
Or I must write my own save methods?

Comment: If you really need to save an instance of a Pane or any other javafx control then you are doing something wrong or you are thinking the problem wrong.

Comment: Generally-accepted design strategies for UI applications are based on the MVC ("Model-View-Controller") design. In all of these, the model holds the data, and the controller/view ensure that the UI displays the current state of the model. If you follow one of these designs, all you need to do is save the data from the model. Once you have written your model class(es), saving the data from them should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: I use scene builder and mvc model for javafx, but I need to save the state of nodes, for example the slider value, or a text of a textfield.
I dont know if there is an easy solution to save this as an object and recall it

Comment: Those values should be part of your model; just save them from the model. There's no built-in API for that, you have to write the code to save the data in whatever format (json, xml, serialized Java objects, etc) you need.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I think that I can create a separate class in every controller for creating an object in init method and saving there every data I need